# Can I share an entire Git project via Gist?

Tags: git, gist

I'm writing a tutorial for users of our API, and want to incorporate code snippets and complete files for example purposes.  I can expose the entire directory structure as a git, for people to download; no problem.  But I'd like to embed specific code on relevant pages in the way that I can via a gist.

I do that by copying each file into gist, pressing "embed", and copying the resulting link into my tutorial page.

However, it seems wasteful to have a git repo all set up with the full files, then have to duplicate it for each file.  Is there a better way to do this?

(Alternatively, if there's a way to embed a reference to a specific file from a git, I could do that too--the use case here is to say, "here's the full sample file" so I'd be fine pulling it that way.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is http://gist-it.appspot.com/

GitHub have this on their "list" but we don't know when it will happen.

Comment: Thanks--tried that but kept getting 'Load failure — Timed out' -- is this normal?

Comment: @Dave Rodger - Yeah, I am getting the same. I have used this before, so this can be due to the site going over AppSpot limits. But as @Mark Longair said, you should be able to whip up something like this. Maybe you can contact the author of gist-it for some quick ideas.

Comment: The "Load failure" is only for the automatic generation feature on the homepage. If you put together the link manually as shown (or by a self-made script), it still works.

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann Yeah you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. @DaveRodger - you can construct the `<script>` yourself as per the example in the site and it works. I just tried it out.

Comment: Does anyone know if github supports this now? or do you still need to use something like gist-it.appspot.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that embedding any file, not just those from gists, is something that GitHub are planning, but which haven't been done yet:

- http://support.github.com/discussions/feature-requests/579-embed-files-like-gist
- http://support.github.com/discussions/gist/238-can-any-github-hosted-file-become-an-embeddable-gist

However, you could do something like this yourself by loading the files dynamically from the "raw" links on GitHub and using [SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/) to render them nicely.

Comment: Thanks, Mark.  Nice to see it's on their list, even if it doesn't solve my problem immediately.  I'll give some thought to doing it myself via the route you suggest.